# How to get all the items in sql using query based on a WHERE clause

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sql

I am new to database and I am trying to get all the data from table whose category column is equal to 1. This is my first attempt. Can someone please guide me where I am doing wrong?

```
public Cursor getAllFamilyMovies()
    {
        return database.query("movies", new String[] {"_id", "name"},
                "category=1", null, null, null, "name");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "whereclause" and "whereargs" need to be separated as shown below:

```
public Cursor getAllFamilyMovies() {
    return database.query("movies", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, "category = ?", new String[] {"1"}, null, null, "name");
}
```

Comment: This works only if the values in the `category` column actually are strings.